# Manage the memory of a class passed as a void* callback argument

Tags: c++

I am using an API which defines a callback for receiving mobile messages:

```cpp
typedef void (*UserCallback)(void* user_data);
void SetCallback(UserCallback callback, void* user_data);
```

I am using a class method as the callback:

```cpp
class MyClass {
  public:
    MyClass() {}    

    void InitCallback() {
      SetCallback(ReceiveDataFromCallback, this);
    }
   
    static void ReceiveDataFromCallback(void* user_data) {
      MyClass* my_class_instance = static_cast<MyClass*>(user_data)
      my_class_instance->DoSomething();
    }

    void DoSomething() {
       // do something
    }
};
```

`MyClass` is then used as a `std::shared_ptr` in another class:

```cpp
class AnotherClass {
  public:
    AnotherClass() {
      my_class_ = std::make_shared<MyClass>();
      my_class_->InitCallback();
    } 

  private:
    std::shared_ptr<MyClass> my_class_;
};
```

Using this implementation, It is possible to get a bad access error in the method `DoSomething`. This is because, while `my_class_instance->DoSomething()` is busy, the `AnotherClass` instance can be deallocated, resulting in the `my_class_` pointer also being deallocated, and thus, the `my_class_instance` pointer is left dangling.

The crux of the issue is, how can I manage the memory (e.g. increment the reference count) of the `MyClass` smart pointer passed into the callback setter as a `void*`?

If this is not possibly with this implementation, how can this be implemented in a memory safe way?

Comment: Would you like MyClass to be preserved though until the callback occurs, even if AnotherClass gets deallocated/destroyed?

Comment: If the callback data is stored in a `void*` then there is no way to be notified when that pointer's lifetime ends. So it is not possible to implement shared ownership with a raw `void*`.

Comment: "_the `AnotherClass` instance can be deallocated, resulting in the `my_class_` pointer also being deallocated, and thus, the `my_class_instance` pointer is left dangling._" - If that's the problem, I'm guessing that you use threads and haven't used the proper synchronizing primitives, like mutexes etc.

Comment: @UziGoozie I'd like `MyClass` to also be destroyed when `AnotherClass` is destroyed. The issue is that, since the callback is asynchronous, it is possible that the callback is invoked while `MyClass` is being deallocated, resulting in the `my_class_instance` dangling pointer.

Comment: This question is confusing. You threw a bunch of statements about user data and reference counters yet I fail to understand what is the problem, why do you have it, or how you try to solve it? Can you make the question clearer?

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this is to know when the library performing the callback is **done** doing so (*i.e.*, when it will make no more calls to it).  That might look like

```
callbacks_init();
{
  AnotherClass ac;

  // provoke some number of callbacks...

  callbacks_wait();  // synchronize with other threads
}
callbacks_fini();    // could also be an RAII wrapper
```

Note that in this case there’s no need for `std::shared_ptr`; it collects multiple “potential points of destruction” and picks the last one, but here the challenge is identifying **one** such point.